# writing print output to csv selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, csv

I'm totally new to selenium and python and I can't figure out the way when writing to CSV with pandas.
Basically I'm trying to write the link attributes of elements but I don't know how to wrap them properly.

Here's the code

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@href, "/c/")]')

for link in elem:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['url'])
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(**what should i write here to get the href values?**, columns=['url'])], sort=False)
df.to_csv('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/urls.csv', index=False)
```

What I'm looking for is to save the URLs I printed out to csv, but I don't know how to locate them. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this.  Since your code is already set up to create a dataframe you could just create a list of all the urls and then when you create your dataframe use that list.

Tweaks below

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@href, "/c/")]')

#create empty list
url_list = []
for link in elem:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
    ##append link to list
    url_list.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

# now that you have the list you can just create your dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame(url_list,columns=['url'])
df.to_csv('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/urls.csv', index=False)
```